# Paste text without formatting with Unicode support. Error with Transform in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I found the following AutoHotkey snippet [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11427&highlight=paste%20text%20formatting) to paste text without formatting with support for Unicode:

```
<^<+v::                          ; Text–only paste from ClipBoard
   Clip0 = %ClipBoardAll%
   Transform, UC, Unicode         ; Save Unicode text
   Transform, Clipboard, Unicode, %UC%
   Send ^v                       ; For best compatibility: SendPlay
   Sleep 50                      ; Don't change clipboard while it is pasted! (Sleep > 0)
   ClipBoard = %Clip0%           ; Restore original ClipBoard
   VarSetCapacity(Clip0, 0)      ; Free memory
Return
```

However, when I run it on the newest version of `AutoHotkey_L`, it complains with the following error:

```
Line 4:     Parameter #2 invalid.
```

where `Line 4` refers to the line `Transform, UC, Unicode         ; Save Unicode text`.

The snippet is supposed to work according to the comments on the link above. Any thoughts why I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of AutoHotkey_L did you install? During installation the current version will ask you to choose between Unicode and ANSI. If you opted for Unicode then the Transform command doesn't have a Unicode sub-command. I'm guessing because it's not needed.

From the [AutoHotkey_L](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/) docs for the [Transform](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/Transform.htm) command:

> **Unicode [, String]:** (This command is not available in Unicode builds of AutoHotkey_L.) Retrieves or stores Unicode text on the
>   clipboard. Note: The entire clipboard may be saved and restored by
>   means of ClipboardAll, which allows "Transform Unicode" to operate
>   without losing the original contents of the clipboard.

I'm not using the Unicode version so I can't test, but I'm assuming that in the Unicode version of AutoHotkey_L any text retrieved from the clipboard will already be Unicode so this should work:

```
<^<+v::                          ; Text–only paste from ClipBoard
   Clip0 = %ClipBoardAll%
   Clipboard = %Clipboard%  ; Convert clipboard text to plain text.
   Send ^v                       ; For best compatibility: SendPlay
   Sleep 50                      ; Don't change clipboard while it is pasted! (Sleep > 0)
   ClipBoard = %Clip0%           ; Restore original ClipBoard
   VarSetCapacity(Clip0, 0)      ; Free memory
Return
```